# Best semantic way to determine if a row DOESN'T exist?

Tags: mysql

I can easily do this in my application:

```
$userExists = DB::getBool('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id = ?', $id);
```

And then I can do

```
if (! $userExists) {
    # yada yada
}
```

But I prefer to avoid `!` when I can.  I'd prefer to have `$userDoesntExist`.

As far as I can see, I have two options.  This, but we still have a `!`:

```
$userDoesntExist = ! DB::getBool('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id = ?', $id);
```

or, a quick experiment reveals that this works too:

```
$userDoesntExist = DB::getBool('SELECT NOT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id = ?', $id);
```

But that feels similarly ugly.

`COUNT(*)` is unintuitive in all of the above as well (especially `NOT COUNT(*)`) as I don't care about the number, I just want to know yes or no...

I wonder if there's a nicer way, using something that I don't already know?  I've tried googling and scanning the documentation but nothing jumped out at me.

Comment: Give a try to: `select not exists (select 1 from users where id = ?)`

Comment: `SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE id = ?) AS user_not_exists ;` (McNets was faster ;) : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b6456fdc86c59a86728c307cfa5c47a

Comment: Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If it is, then `COUNT(*)` is overkill since there can't be more than 1.

Comment: Agreed @RickJames - I didn't realise that `SELECT 1` was an option. When drafting queries for swiftness I sometimes do `ORDER BY 3` (etc) to order by the third column, so I might have guessed that `SELECT 1` would try to pick the first column from the first table discovered in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @Codemonkey - No, it is not like `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`..  In `EXISTS( SELECT <<anything>> FROM ...)`, it does not matter what is used -- `0` works; `1` works; `*` works; `a,b,c` works.  People use `1` because it is simple, short, and means 'true'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `id` is unique (such as `PRIMARY KEY`)

```
SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE id = ?
```

will be `NULL` or `1`. -- Will `GetBool()` work correctly with such?

**More**

Let's dissect `NOT COUNT(*)`.  `COUNT(*)` is 0 or more than zero.  `NOT` is expecting a boolean.  `0`, when treated as boolean, means `false`; more than zero is treated as `true`.  Hence `NOT COUNT(*)` with no matches `gives true`; else `false`.

`EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ... )` gives `true` if there are *any* rows that match.  It is faster than `SELECT COUNT(*) ... > 0` because it `EXISTS` can stop as soon as one row is found, whereas the other formulation must find the exact count (only to then simply test for "> 0").

Your formulation is `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`.  This is dissected as

1. Do the slow approach of finding out exactly how many.  This will  get 0 or more than 0.
2. Treat that as boolean.  0 = false, more than zero = true.

Unfortunately, the optimal phrasing, `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )` is just an expression, and the API you are using probably cannot handle just expressions, but rather must work with a `SELECT`.  (Is this true?)  Hence I suggested

```
SELECT ( EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... ) )
```

In a stored routine (Function or Procedure or Trigger), you can say

```
IF ( EXISTS( SELECT ... ) ) THEN ...
```

You should consider building a stored routine instead of client code.

**IODKU?**

The common use for testing the existence of a row is to decide whether to insert or update.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl
    (...) VALUES (...)
```

Will insert a row if the row does not already exist (based on `PRIMARY KEY` and any `UNIQUE` keys).

```
INSERT INTO tbl
    (...) VALUES (...)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;
```

is called IODKU or Upsert.  It *either* `INSERTs` or `UPDATEs`, depending on whether the row exists.  This is quite efficient when it is what you want.

Either of those can handle multiple rows at the same time.  Change

```
VALUES(...)
```

to (for multiple explicit values):

```
VALUES(...),(...),(...)...
```

or to (for values from another table):

```
SELECT ...
```

Comment: It will, but it's still returning the inverse of the question I'm actually asking.